# If someone file for a full patent after i file for a PPA can they steal my idea?

Tags: patent-infringement, provisional-application, non-provisional

This information may be wrong but as im researching patents and PPAs. I heard if i get a PPA then after someone file a full patent if i don't get a full patent after my PPA ended they can legally take my idea. This doesn't make sense personally but i thought I'd ask to make sure i fully understand how things work. So is this possible?

Comment: By "legally take my idea", are you asking whether another party can freely use the invention that you have described in your provisional?

Comment: Yes, but only if they file a non provisional after i already filed a provisional. I was told if i didn't file a non provisional if they already have ine they can take my idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repatenting someone else's dropped provisionals](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17235/repatenting-someone-elses-dropped-provisionals)

Comment: It does seem to be a duplicate, but it may not be, depending on what you mean by "take". That is to say, the question (and subsequent comment) seems to be conflating a few different concepts, which make the question a bit hard to grok. Freedom to operate is independent of whether someone holds a patent. And then there is the orthogonal question of using (whether in production or for patenting) an idea of someone else's without permission. I'm not quite sure which part you're concerned about.

Comment: What i mean is some stated if i get a PPA and while i have my PPA someone file for a non provisional, if whrn my PPA is up, i must file for a non provisional or else ill lose my rights to there full patent "EVEN" if i file for another PPA. It will get trumped by there non provisional